# How to rank collection of objects

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I have class, for example

```
class Person{
    Integer rank;
    Double profit;
    Person(Integer rank, Double profit){
        this.rank = rank;
        this.profit = profit;
    }
    Person(Double profit){
        this(0, profit);
    }
}
```

I want to rank list of sorted by profit persons with rank evaluation.
So that

```
rank(Arrays.asList(
    new Person(30), 
    new Person(20), 
    new Person(20), 
    new Person(10))
)
```

will be produced into list

```
new Person(1, 30), 
new Person(2, 20), 
new Person(2, 20), 
new Person(3, 10)
```

Also I want to do it using custom `Collector` (or something similar) from Java 8 and not to use simple loops.

Comment: You can simply do it by using `Comparator`. Read more about `Comparator & Comparable` in Java: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: @user2004685 with `Comparator` I can for example sort my collection but how can I set ranks to its elements?

Comment: Your example doesn't make sense to me.  Your single parameter constructor sets the rank to `0`, so how do the `Person` objects magically gain a rank when you're sorting them?

Comment: You can first sort the objects and then assign the ranks later in linear time by doing a single pass over all the list objects.

Comment: @azurefrog I am sorry for inaccuracy, I renamed `sort()` function to `rank()`

Comment: So, you want to first sort the list, then go back through and add ranks? Then just do what @user2004685 suggested and write a two-pass method that first sorts, and then adds ranks afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use a custom collector to which we pass all the stuff from outside. The collector will get ranking and constructor from the caller. We would like to call it like this:

```
public List<Person> rank(List<Person> people) {
        return people
                .stream()
                .sorted(Comparator.<Person>comparingDouble(x -> x.profit).reversed())
                .collect(new IntegerRankingCollector<>(
                        Comparator.comparingDouble(p -> p.profit),  // how to differentiate rankings
                        p -> p.rank,    // where to get rank for an element which was already ranked
                        (p, rank) -> new Person(rank, p.profit)     // how to create an element from another element values and a rank
                ));
    }
```

This collector can be implemented like [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--) but with an accumulator method that:

1. gets the rank of the previous element
2. increases it if current element rank should be different from
   previous element rank
3. creates an element with the new rank

Here is how it looks and it should work for ordered streams:

```
public class IntegerRankingCollector<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> {
        ...

    public IntegerRankingCollector(Comparator<? super T> comparator, Function<T, Integer> ranker, BiFunction<T, Integer, T> creator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.ranker = ranker;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (list, current) -> {
            ArrayList<T> right = new ArrayList<>();
            right.add(creator.apply(current, 1));
            combiner().apply(list, right);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            int rankAdjustment = getRankAdjustment(left, right);
            for (T t : right)
                left.add(creator.apply(t, rankAdjustment + ranker.apply(t)));
            return left;
        };
    }

    private int getRankAdjustment(List<T> left, List<T> right) {
        Optional<T> lastElementOnTheLeft = optGet(left, left.size() - 1);
        Optional<T> firstElementOnTheRight = optGet(right, 0);

        if (!lastElementOnTheLeft.isPresent() || !firstElementOnTheRight.isPresent())
            return 0;
        else if (comparator.compare(firstElementOnTheRight.get(), lastElementOnTheLeft.get()) == 0)
            return ranker.apply(lastElementOnTheLeft.get()) - 1;
        else
            return ranker.apply(lastElementOnTheLeft.get());
    }

    private Optional<T> optGet(List<T> list, int index) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
            return Optional.empty();
        else
            return Optional.of(list.get(index));
    }

        ...
    }
```

For completeness, this is the full code of the class. I copied the rest from `Collectors.toList`:

```
public class IntegerRankingCollector<T> implements Collector<T, List<T>, List<T>> {

    private static final Set<Characteristics> CHARACTERISTICSS = Collections.unmodifiableSet(EnumSet.of(Characteristics.IDENTITY_FINISH));
    private Comparator<? super T> comparator;
    private BiFunction<T, Integer, T> creator;
    private Function<T, Integer> ranker;

    public IntegerRankingCollector(Comparator<? super T> comparator, Function<T, Integer> ranker, BiFunction<T, Integer, T> creator) {
        this.comparator = comparator;
        this.ranker = ranker;
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<List<T>, T> accumulator() {
        return (list, current) -> {
            ArrayList<T> right = new ArrayList<>();
            right.add(creator.apply(current, 1));
            combiner().apply(list, right);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<List<T>> combiner() {
        return (left, right) -> {
            int rankAdjustment = getRankAdjustment(left, right);
            for (T t : right)
                left.add(creator.apply(t, rankAdjustment + ranker.apply(t)));
            return left;
        };
    }

    private int getRankAdjustment(List<T> left, List<T> right) {
        Optional<T> lastElementOnTheLeft = optGet(left, left.size() - 1);
        Optional<T> firstElementOnTheRight = optGet(right, 0);

        if (!lastElementOnTheLeft.isPresent() || !firstElementOnTheRight.isPresent())
            return 0;
        else if (comparator.compare(firstElementOnTheRight.get(), lastElementOnTheLeft.get()) == 0)
            return ranker.apply(lastElementOnTheLeft.get()) - 1;
        else
            return ranker.apply(lastElementOnTheLeft.get());
    }

    private Optional<T> optGet(List<T> list, int index) {
        if (list == null || list.isEmpty())
            return Optional.empty();
        else
            return Optional.of(list.get(index));
    }


    @Override
    public Supplier<List<T>> supplier() {
        return ArrayList::new;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<List<T>, List<T>> finisher() {
        return l -> l;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return CHARACTERISTICSS;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

1. firstly sort the list with custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html);
2. make new list with profits without duplicates([`distinct()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) method);
3. set appropriate ranks, using [`forEach()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-).

I hope it will be helpful.

```
List<Person> l  = Arrays.asList(new Person(30.0), new Person(20.0), new Person(20.0), new Person(10.0));
Collections.sort(l,(Person o1, Person o2)->o1.profit.compareTo(o2.profit));
List<Double> p = l.stream().map(a -> a.profit).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
l.forEach(a -> a.setRank(p.indexOf(a.profit) + 1));
```

Comment: your algorithm is very ineffective. Last line has quadratic complexity, think about it. And if you hold in the list objects with the same .equals() result, it will give you even wrong ranking.